# If $X_1, X_2, ...$ are independent and $E(X_n) =0$ and $E(X^2_n)$ is bounded and exists, how to show that the average converges almost surely to $0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to show that if $X_1, X_2, ...$ are independent and $E(X_n) =0$ and $E(X^2_n)\leq M < \infty$, then $\frac{X_1+X_2+ \ldots +X_n}{n} \to 0$ almost surely. I am able to show this in the i.i.d. case but run into problems when I loosen the condition that the $X_i's$ are not necessarily identically distributed. Should the proof be that much different? It seems to me that no matter what I do, I still need a condition that the fourth moment is bounded. Is it possible to do this without the condition of a bounded fourth moment? Thanks.

Comment: for iid case: CLT?

Comment: @hermes You'd be hard-pressed to find a counter-example given the proof below. 4th moment has little-to-now relevance to convergence of averages.

Comment: More generally, if $E(X^2_k)/k\to 0$, $S_n/n\to 0$ in distribution and if $E(X^2_k)/k\to C\\<\infty$ and $E(X^{2+\delta}_k)/k^{1+\delta}\to 0$ for some $\delta>0$, then $S_n/n\to N(0,C/2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n Var(k^{-1}X_k)\le \sum_{k=1}^n k^{-2}M<\infty.$$

So using [Kolmogorov two-series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_two-series_theorem) and Kronecker's lemma $n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n{X_k}\to 0$ a.s.

Comment: Is $\sum_{k=1}^n Var(k^{-1}X_k)<\infty$ a necessary condition for a.e. convergence? A weaker $\frac 1 {n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n Var(X_k)\to 0$ is enough for convergence in $L^2$.

Comment: @A.S. It's a sufficient condition for a.s. convergence of $\sum (k^{-1}X_k)$

Comment: My question is whether $S_n/n\to 0$ a.s. when $var(X_k)/k\to 0$ but $\sum_k var(X_k)/k^2\to \infty$.